# WebRTC issue-! navigator.mediaDevices not present in your browser in WKWebView

Tags: swift, webrtc, wkwebview, swift5

I new to developing with swift and currently trying to develop a iOS app with Swift UI. Part of my app uses a separately developed Augmented Reality web app that I was planning on accessing through a WKWebView . Currently I can access the web app this fine through Safari and SFSafariViewController and get video/camera input just fine. However, with the WKWebview it just shows as a blank screen with the alert WebRTC issue-! navigator.mediaDevices not present in your browser.

Is this a limitation on WKWebView and is there anyway around this? I have NSCameraUsageDescription already configured in my info.plist. I have tried:

- [WKWebView does not allow camera access in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56646575/wkwebview-does-not-allow-camera-access-in-application)
- [Enable Camera and Mic access in wkwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916436/enable-camera-and-mic-access-in-wkwebview)

My code is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct SwiftUIWebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: WebViewModel
    let webView = WKWebView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SwiftUIWebView>) -> WKWebView {


        self.webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        self.webView.configuration.allowsAirPlayForMediaPlayback = false
        self.webView.configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true
        self.webView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all
        self.webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        return self.webView

    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SwiftUIWebView>) {
        return
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

        private var viewModel: WebViewModel

        init(_ viewModel: WebViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print("Web Page Loaded")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you solve it broo, plaese share it